# MongoDB select where in array of _id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

is possible in mongo db to select collection's documents like in SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE _id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

or if i have a `_id array` i must select one by one and then recompose the `array/object` of results?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Easy :)

```
db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : [1,2,3,4] } } );
```

taken from: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#mongodb-query-op.-in

Comment: Do we still get benefits of indexing? IDs in that case are passed as plain strings...

Comment: You do. However time complexity is linear (n), not logarithmic/constant. Without index it would be n^2.

Comment: Is it not `O(log(n) * m)` where `n` is the size of the collection and `m` is the number of ids passed ?

Comment: U have to use ObjectId function, if "_id" is the ID object — {_id: {$in: [ObjectId("5a633609670aeb6f93b88b23")]}}

Answer (score 17):

Because mongodb uses `bson` and for bson is important attribute types. and because `_id` is `ObjectId` you must use like this:

```
db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : [ObjectId('1'),ObjectId('2')] } } );
```

and in `mongodb compass` use like this:

```
{ "_id" : { $in : [ObjectId('1'),ObjectId('2')] } }
```

**Note:** objectId in string has `24` length.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

```
var ids = ["5883d387971bb840b7399130","5883d389971bb840b7399131","5883d38a971bb840b7399132"];

var oids = [];
ids.forEach(function(item){
oids.push(new ObjectId(item));
});

.find({ _id: {$in : oids}})
```

Comment: Thanks. Remember to define ObjectID like this: var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Answer (score 6):

[image: list is a array of ids]

In this code list is the array of ids in user collection

```
var list = ["5883d387971bb840b7399130","5883d389971bb840b7399131","5883d38a971bb840b7399132"]

    .find({ _id: {$in : list}})
```

Comment: The code is not working. It seems have to set IDs as ObjectId("5883d387971bb840b7399130")

Comment: How do we do set them to ObjectIds programmatically? I tried the approach suggested by @klipmode in one of the answers, but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find by user and also by another field like conditionally, you can easily do it like beneath with spread and ternary operator using `aggregate` and `match`

```
 const p_id = patient_id;
    let fetchingReports = await Reports.aggregate([
      ...(p_id
        ? [
            {
              $match: {
                createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
                patient_id: p_id,
              },
            },
          ]
        : [
            {
              $match: {
                createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
              },
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

**The query should be something like this:**

```
db.collection.find( { 
        "_id": {
            "$in": [
                "475B9A5029D21",
                "385D808029D81",
                "C3463BD029DBB",
                "B839DB5029FFF"
            ]
        }
 } );
```