# A lot of queries with "or"

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, database

I'm trying to convert a database from MySQL to MongoDB but I have a problem. I do not know how the query should look for MongoDB.

```
   $hd='';
   $count = count($args[1]);
   for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++){
       $hd.="playerId='" . $args[1][$i] . "' OR ";
   }
   $hd.="playerId='".$args[1][$count-1]."'";
   $h1=mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM player where ".$hd));
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which is why one should use a DAL, such as PDO. :)

Comment: What do you mean with "how to fix it"? This looks more like a rewriting request, with no prior attempts of your own. See [MongoDB queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries) to read up on it first, then the according [PHP manual section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php).

Comment: That's only a query for SQL not for Mongo. What do you mean by your question? Also you are using vulnerable code also you are using soon to be deprecated `mysql_` driver.

Comment: On a side note: Your MySQL query could be improved by making a list of the args: `$list = implode(",", $args[1])` then put it into the statement with the `in` clause: `SELECT * FROM player where playerId in ($list)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [Mongo db select where in array of _id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713363/mongo-db-select-where-in-array-of-id)

I'm not that familiar with `MongoDB`, but instead of using multiple `OR` you can use `IN()` statement should make your query more readable:

```
$h1 = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM player where playerId IN (" . implode(", ", $args[1]) . ")"
);
```

As for MondoDB I think this should get you the result you need:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB("database"); // your db
$mc = new MongoCollection($db, 'player');
$mc->find(
    array(
        'playerId' => array(
            '$in' => $args[1]
        )
    )
);
```

If you find some grammar errors, please don't shoot me :)

Comment: $in doesn't work like that...it is an array as in `$in=>$args`

Comment: @Sammaye As I said, I'm not that into MongoDB //edit: I've changed the code ;)

Comment: The `mysql_` fucntions in PHP has been deprecated as of version 5.3.0. User `mysqli_`.

Comment: @jurgemaister I think he was just replicating the OPs knowledge there

Comment: I know, but when you suggest changes, like replacing OR with IN, why not go all the way and correct the use of the API as well?

Answer (score 0):

**[PHP - MongoDB Advanced Queries](http://coderwall.com/p/aymsvw)**

```
$collection->find([
    'playerId' => ['$in' => [1, 2, 3]]
]);
```