# Mongo query to find documents where any of the field's elements match any of the query param elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've scoured the docs and google. Maybe I just need help formulating the question.

I have a field that stores an array of values. We'll call it "tags" for simplicity. I want to be able to search for all documents that match ANY of the multiple tags I search on. Put another way, I want to find all records that are tagged with at least one (not necessarily all) of these tags. Here's an example.

**Documents :**

```
{name: "My Thing 1", tags: ["cool", "important", "anothertag"]},
{name: "My Thing 2", tags: ["cool"]},
{name: "My Thing 3", tags: ["cool", "important"]}
{name: "My Thing 4", tags: ["important", "anothertag"]}
{name: "My Thing 5", tags: []}
{name: "My Thing 6", tags: ["anothertag"]}
```

**Query:** `["important", "cool"]`

**Result:** documents 1-4 (not 5-6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB select where in array of \_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713363/mongodb-select-where-in-array-of-id)

Comment: You need to use `$in` operator as suggested in above link, It should help you out of this issue.

Comment: I don't think that's it since the field I'm querying against is itself an array, unlike the _id field in that example.

Comment: If should work, Can you please try it first & let us know, FYI I've tested samething & it's working !!

Comment: @whoami Well SOB it worked. I must have written my test query wrong because I thought I'd tried $in before posting. Thanks for the info and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment by whoami. $in does the trick.